# Cannot start fabric-ca server natively

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have been following [this](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#install) for setting up a fabric-ca server in my network of 2 organizations, 4 peers (2 in each).

I have two questions:

1. In the documentation, it says that we can start server locally. When I try to do the same, I'm not able to do it and getting the following error :
   `fabric-ca-server: command not found` . So I tried using a docker image and the server now works as a docker image.
2. Now when I try to run the `fabric-ca-client` command, it cannot find the client configuration in the fabric-ca-client home. The `FABRIC_CA_HOME` environment variable is set as `/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server' in the container. I'm confused as to what I might be missing here.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you followed the instructions, then the `fabric-ca-server` executable will be under `$GOPATH/bin`, you will need to add this to your `PATH`, via `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`. Remember to also set `FABRIC_CA_HOME`.
2. Assuming you're also using the client natively, it should also be under `$GOPATH/bin`. In a separate terminal, set `FABRIC_CA_HOME` to a different path. Then you can enroll the admin user, for example: `fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:password@localhost:7054`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is coming because you have not set the GOPATH path.
After cloning the CA repo set the GOPATH to the given directory.

For setting up GOPATH:
(Ubuntu)
If you don’t set a GOPATH, the default will be used.

You have to add $GOPATH/bin to your PATH to execute any binary installed in $GOPATH/bin, or you need to type $GOPATH/bin/the-command. 
Add this to your ~/.bash_profile

> `export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH`

Current GOPATH command:

> `go env GOPATH`

Changing the GOPATH command:

> `export GOPATH=$HOME/your-desired-path`

So. change the 'your-desired-path' to your Fabric-CA repo directory.

Answer (score 1):

You will be facing issue with certain versions of golang. Set the flags explicitly using CGO_LDFLAGS_ALLOW='-Wl,--no-as-needed'
Reference -

1. [Error while running make command using Fabric 1.0.6 after all the 15 steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786309/error-while-running-make-command-using-fabric-1-0-6-after-all-the-15-steps)
2. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23739

   ➜  fabric-ca git:(release-1.0) go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/...

   go build github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11: invalid flag in #cgo LDFLAGS: -I/usr/local/share/libtool

   ➜  fabric-ca git:(release-1.0) **export CGO_LDFLAGS_ALLOW='-Wl,--no-as-needed'**

   ➜  fabric-ca git:(release-1.0) make