# Error while running make command using Fabric 1.0.6 after all the 15 steps

Tags: makefile, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I am installing fabric in a custom path $HOME//gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric using the *make* command but after installing all the 15 steps, I am getting the following error

```
Step 15/15 : LABEL org.hyperledger.fabric.version=1.0.2       org.hyperledger.fabric.base.version=0.3.2
 ---> Running in ed05a67810db
Removing intermediate container ed05a67810db
 ---> 99b4b0b28957
Successfully built 99b4b0b28957
Successfully tagged hyperledger/fabric-javaenv:latest
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-javaenv hyperledger/fabric-javaenv:x86_64-1.0.2
build/bin/peer
CGO_CFLAGS=" " GOBIN=/root/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin go install -tags "" -ldflags "-X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.Version=1.0.2 -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseVersion=0.3.2 -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseDockerLabel=org.hyperledger.fabric -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.DockerNamespace=hyperledger -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseDockerNamespace=hyperledger" github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
go build github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11: invalid flag in #cgo LDFLAGS: -Wl,--no-as-needed
Makefile:227: recipe for target 'build/bin/peer' failed
make: *** [build/bin/peer] Error 1


Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
go version go1.9.4 linux/amd64
OS : Ubuntu 16.04
```

I have set the following path also

```
$ mkdir $HOME/gopath
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/gopath
$ export GOROOT=$HOME/go
$ export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Jira Link: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2218 which I have already done

Answer (score 2):

It is a known issue in go 1.9.4:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23739

While go people are fixing it, you can manually whitelist the flags before starting **make**:

```
$ export CGO_LDFLAGS_ALLOW='-Wl,--no-as-needed'
$ make
```

Alternatively you can just downgrade to go 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know you don't need to build the fabric itself.
You just need to have sources in the gopath, as your chaincode will need this, when you are building your chaincode for the blockchain itself.
In addition you will probably also need to install the fabric-ca for your chaincode to build successfully, if you use the certificate-stuff.
This is sufficient to check if you installed fabric correctly:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
make unit-test
```

Keep going if this works.
I found this confusing at first as well ;)

Comment: Hi Christian, I am specifically installing make peer for peer nodes and make orderer for order nodes. I am not sure about unit-test and how to work on it. Thank you very much for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume you switch to golang `1.9.4` or greater hence I belive this actually related to [following issue](https://github.com/miekg/pkcs11/issues/63), to solve it you need to update vendor dependencies:

```
govendor fetch github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11
```

Next continue to build binaries and run tests.

Comment: I am getting issues installing govendor. As a quick fix I have downgraded to 1.9 from 1.9.4.

Comment: Hi I am running the command sudo go get github.com/kardianos/govendor to install in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS # runtime
/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/proc.go:1257:14: write barrier prohibited by caller; allocm

Comment: But I am Getting the error as said in previous comment. I will solve and try the govendor command in 1.9.4. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I'm not sure what is the real problem with having govendor installed, should be fairly simple process, also not sure why do you need root privileges?